# I have to convert an input file of ASCII and non ASCII characters to a binary vector using Fortran 90

Tags: binary, fortran, character

Is there any routine available ? I didn´t find any

Thanks

Comment: I have to be honest and say I have no idea what you are trying to do. Could you please expand your question to provide more details - an example could well be useful

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you want to read a binary file that contains bytes for printable characters like "A"=65 and nonprintable characters like "ESC"=27 something like this might help?

```
integer(kind=selected_int_kind(1)), dimension(1000) :: vector
open(unit=10,file='data.data', access='stream', form='unformatted')
i=1
read(unit=10, iostat=ios) vector(i)
do while(ios==0)
  i=i+1
  read(unit=10, iostat=ios) vector(i)
enddo
```

For simplicity I assumed that the length of the vector is at most 1000. The vector will now contain the decimal representation of the ASCII characters in the input file.

Comment: I rephrase my problem: I want to read for example a PDF file, storing its binary representation in a vector

thanks for the comments

Comment: Hugo, my code snippet is from a little code that reads a BMP file so I guess it could be adapted to a PDF file as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will try an adaptation of your code.By the way: one of my students solved the problem in a couple of minutes using Python